# Ruby on Rails : ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in PageController#insert_table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error, i tried it all if i put "skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token " or anything like this the error won't show up but the page gets refreshed automatically and i don't want it to get refreshed. I am new to rails and don't know to approach this issue, please help!

This is my HTML

```
<form id="contactform" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label class=" control-label">prefix</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="prefix" name="prefix">               
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="tmp">tmp</option>
                        <option value="tbl">tbl</option>
                        <option value="ref">ref</option>
                        <option value="client">client</option>
                </select><br>

 <label class=" control-label">client</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="client" name="client">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="kapow">kapow</option>
                        <option value="perfect_africa">perfect_africa</option>
                        <option value="earth_class_mail">earth_class_mail</option>
                        <option value="amzn_seller">amzn_seller</option>
                </select>  <br>                   

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-4">
     <input type="file" name="file" id="myFile">
                <div id="temp_display"></div><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="filename" id="my_file_name" value="">         
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="concat">Concat</button><br><br>

</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#concat').click(function () {   
 $('#contactform')
  .formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        prefix: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The prefix is required'
                },
            }
        },
           client: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The client is required'
                },
            }
        }                     
    }
  });
 });
});
```

This is my controller

```
class PageController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]

def home
end

def insert_table
end 

def create_table
  helpers.create_table
end  

def index
end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several things that seem to be off:

1. The InvalidAuthenticityToken error - this shows up, because you use a `POST` request to send data to the server but do not pass the `authenticity_token` parameter that is required by rails for `POST` and `PUT` operations. If you don't want the form to actually submit, you don't have to worry about it here.
2. The reason why your page is refreshing is because of the `submit` button's default `click` event, which submits the form. To prevent that you have to adjust event handler

`$('#concat').click(function (e) {e.preventDefault() ... })`

This will override the default behaviour of the `submit` button.